# LIMIT the mysql record using Pagination Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display maximum 20 pages and each page has 10 posts that means I need to limit 200 records in MySQL query am using this code.

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 200 $start, $limit";
```

start and limit is using for pagination page limit, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have 200 and a $limit? Also, define "not work". What errors are you getting? What are you seeing vs. what you are expecting to see? Have you tried outputting the SQL and running it against your SQL DB to see what is happening?

Comment: Also if those variables are coming from user input you are open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have LIMIT 200, and then also limit 10 in these as well.

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

This will limit it to whatever `$limit` is, and start at whatever index `$start` is.

If you really need to limit it to 200 rows, and then have pagination within these, you should either do it in PHP, or create a **[`MySQL View`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)**.

Comment: i just need to display 20 pages, because i have a big database.. and every time when i click the next page it loads all the record and takes hell of a time, so i just want to display only 20 pages and 10 posts each page.. like this my script will load pages faster..how can i do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only 10 records per request you should:

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start, 10";
```

Comment: is there any error message? show me full code of your page please?